# Aggregating winners/losers without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, window-functions

I have a situation where i'm trying to first determine the winner and loser salespersons (across whatever time period), then aggregate the results into a total winning amount and a total losing amount.  I can accomplish it with the below using a CTE but I have a feeling there must be a way to do this in one statement using a window function or something like that.  I've attached some sample data below.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```sql
drop table if exists #source

create table #source (
    region  varchar(25),
    salesperson varchar(25),
    amount  float,
    period_date date
)


insert into #source
select region, salesperson, amount, period_date
from  (values
('Americas','Johanna Vandervort', -200, '2020-01-01'),
('Americas','Dagmar Kuhn', 100, '2020-01-01'),
('Americas','Arno Schmitt', 300, '2020-01-01'),
('Americas','Matt Mayert', -500, '2020-01-01'),
('Asia','Alanna Brakus', 150, '2020-01-01'),
('Asia','Eldora Toy Jr.', 240, '2020-01-01'),
('Asia','Tate Reichert', -130, '2020-01-01'),
('Asia','Jacynthe Stark', 120, '2020-01-01'),
('Europe','Bette Armstrong', -600, '2020-01-01'),
('Europe','Neva Bogan', 300, '2020-01-01'),
('Europe','Jillian Windler', 200, '2020-01-01'),
('NJ Asia','Giovanni Prosacco', 550, '2020-01-01'),
('NJ Asia','Elise Heaney', -720, '2020-01-01'),
('NJ Asia','Cooper Prosacco', 140, '2020-01-01'),
('NJ Asia','Morton Steuber', 320, '2020-01-01'),
('Americas','Johanna Vandervort', -720, '2020-02-01'),
('Americas','Dagmar Kuhn', -600, '2020-02-01'),
('Americas','Arno Schmitt', -500, '2020-02-01'),
('Americas','Matt Mayert', -200, '2020-02-01'),
('Asia','Alanna Brakus', -130, '2020-02-01'),
('Asia','Eldora Toy Jr.', 100, '2020-02-01'),
('Asia','Tate Reichert', 120, '2020-02-01'),
('Asia','Jacynthe Stark', 140, '2020-02-01'),
('Europe','Bette Armstrong', 150, '2020-02-01'),
('Europe','Neva Bogan', 200, '2020-02-01'),
('Europe','Jillian Windler', 240, '2020-02-01'),
('NJ Asia','Giovanni Prosacco', 300, '2020-02-01'),
('NJ Asia','Elise Heaney', 300, '2020-02-01'),
('NJ Asia','Cooper Prosacco', 320, '2020-02-01'),
('NJ Asia','Morton Steuber', 550, '2020-02-01')
) as t(region, salesperson, amount, period_date)

with src as (
    -- first aggregating to salesperson grain across time period and segregating winners and losers
    select  case when sum(amount) > 0 then sum(amount) else 0 end as winner_sales
            ,case when sum(amount) <= 0 then sum(amount) else 0 end as loser_sales
            , salesperson
            , region 
    from #source 
    group by 
            region
            , salesperson
)
-- then aggregating results into total winners and total losers
select sum(winner_sales) as winner_sales, sum(loser_sales) as loser_sales, region
from src
group by region
```

Comment: Please define what *you* means by " winner and loser salespersons (across whatever time period)".

Comment: Winner meaning positive sales, loser meaning negative sales.  "Across whatever time period" is a little confusing, all i meant is that i'm summing those sales across all of the time periods, and not grouping by time period.  hope that makes it more clear

Comment: I think CTE is a good solution already but have you try using `over()` , since you want to not use `group by`.

Comment: i've tried using over() but i can't partition by salesperson without including it in the group by, which is what i'm trying to avoid.  I want to just get the winners/losers by salesperson, then aggregate that result.

Comment: what you mean you can't `partition by` without including it in the `group by`? using `over(partition by salesperson)` = `group by salesperson` so you don't have to use `group by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are doing is fine. You cannot put them in a single query, when you try to put it, you will get below error.

> Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 64 Windowed functions cannot be used
> in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

I have put derived table to make it look like single query.

```sql
SELECT region,sum(CASE WHEN total_sales > 0 THEN total_sales else 0 end) as winner_sales,
sum(CASE WHEN total_sales < 0 THEN total_sales else 0 end) as loser_sales
from
(SELECT region,
 sum(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY region,salesperson) as total_sales
from #SOURCE) as t
group by region
```

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+
|  region  | winner_sales | loser_sales |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Americas |            0 |       -4640 |
| Asia     |         1240 |         -20 |
| Europe   |         1880 |        -900 |
| NJ Asia  |         4360 |        -840 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, i was looking to do it in a single statement because even though this was an example, there are about 25 other measures aside from this on that i'm also aggregating, and i didn't want to have to duplicate those aggregations in yet another CTE.  I think it's fine though, since it doesn't seem to impact performance too negatively